# How to get width and height of an element on the page?

Tags: jquery

With the help of the lovely jQuery?

Comment: Here's another hint: take an hour or to off to browse through jQuery's documentation.

Comment: xtifl, do you think I could take even just a minute to read some jQuery's documentation? No way. I'd rather ask some guys on SO.

Comment: While StackOverflow is supposed to have "no question too simple or too small", this question comes off as "I haven't even *tried* to find the answer on my own"

Answer (score 3):

jQuery has two methods, width and height, to do this very thing:

```
$(".myElement").width();
$(".myElement").height();
```

You can also use them to SET values:

```
$(".myElement").width(200); // set element to 200px
```

Further information can be found in the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/width/ and http://api.jquery.com/height/

Note the [other dimension methods](http://api.jquery.com/category/dimensions/) available too:

- `$.innerHeight()` - *Get the current computed height for the first element in the set of matched elements, including padding but not border.*
- `$.innerWidth()` - *Get the current computed width for the first element in the set of matched elements, including padding but not border.*
- `$.outerHeight()` - *Get the current computed height for the first element in the set of matched elements, including padding and border.*
- `$.outerWidth()` - *Get the current computed width for the first element in the set of matched elements, including padding and border.*

Answer (score 2):

Using the [`height(...)`](http://api.jquery.com/height/) and [`width(...)`](http://api.jquery.com/width/) methods:

```
alert($(body).height());
alert($(body).width());
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll never guess...

```
var width = $(selector).width();
var height = $(selector).height();
```

Answer (score 0):

In various useful cases, **the width value is often wrong on Mac Firefox/Mozilla**.

-- where wrong means that if you set an enclosing div to the reported "width" of the text-child, you'll get wrapping.

The problem is that on Mac Firefox/Mozilla, Firefox uses sub-pixel font rendering. And the width that is returned is the floor, not the ceiling of the true width, which is a float.

My [bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=458617) gives a work-around for Firefox, or just always add 1px to the width and you'll be ok.